# Reprocessing - VSCode Reason Refmt breaks project

Tags: visual-studio-code, reason

I'm hunting a fun little bug in a tiny [reprocessing](https://schmavery.github.io/reprocessing/) test: [reprocessing01](https://github.com/codekiln/reasonml-playground/tree/master/reprocessing01).

The project builds just fine until I make a change and trigger `refmt` via vscode, and then the project will no longer compile.

Here's the code that compiles and runs just fine for me before making any changes.

```
open Reprocessing;

type stateT = {
  image: imageT,
};

let setup = (env) => {
  Env.size(~width=800, ~height=600, env);
  let image = Draw.loadImage(
    ~filename="assets/Wave_pattern_by_inkelv1122_on_flickr_800w.jpg", 
    ~isPixel=false, env);
  {
    image: image
  }
};

let draw = ({image} as state, env) => {
  Draw.background(Constants.white, env);
  Draw.image(
    image,
    ~pos=(0,0),
    ~width=Env.width(env),
    ~height=Env.height(env),
    env
  );
  state
};

run(~setup, ~draw, ());
```

If I open the project in vscode, make a change such as adding `let myvar = 42;` at the top, and save to trigger `refmt`, that introduces this error:

```
/Users/myer/dev/react/reasonml-playground/reprocessing01/node_modules/bs-platform/lib/bsc.exe -pp "/Users/myer/dev/react/reasonml-playground/reprocessing01/node_modules/bs-platform/lib/refmt3.exe --print binary"    -bs-super-errors -w -30-40+6+7+27+32..39+44+45+101 -bs-D BSB_BACKEND="bytecode" -nostdlib -I '/Users/myer/dev/react/reasonml-playground/reprocessing01/node_modules/bs-platform/lib/ocaml' -no-alias-deps -color always -c -o src/index.mlast -bs-syntax-only -bs-simple-binary-ast -bs-binary-ast -impl /Users/myer/dev/react/reasonml-playground/reprocessing01/src/index.re
File "/Users/myer/dev/react/reasonml-playground/reprocessing01/src/index.re", line 12, characters 4-5:
Error: 2817: <UNKNOWN SYNTAX ERROR>
```

The line in question is the last one of this code block:

```
Draw.loadImage(
  ~filename="assets/Wave_pattern_by_inkelv1122_on_flickr_800w.jpg",
  ~isPixel=false,
  env,
);
```

After this, the only way out is to revert the code to before the changes introduced by `refmt`.

I suspect that my version of `refmt` is out of sync with the one required by `bsb-native#2.1.1`, but I'm not sure which one to install. I have:

```
$ refmt --version
Reason 3.0.0 @ bee43b0
```

Is there a table that shows compatible versions between [`reason-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reason-cli) and [`bs-platform`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs-platform)?

Are there other ways I should investigate this issue or other potential root causes of this behavior?

UPDATE: 
I was able to upgrade `bsb-native` to the master branch and it worked when building to native until I added some more code in [`reprocessing02`](https://github.com/codekiln/reasonml-playground/blob/master/reprocessing02/src/index.re)

Comment: Could you provide an output of `$ which refmt`? It might be that the `refmt` binary you are checking the version of is the one that is installed globally, whereas the compiler uses the `refmt` from  `node_modules` dir.

Answer (score 1):

this issue is because bsb-native@2.1.1 comes with an old version of refmt (pre version 3) which can't read the code that your global refmt outputs (most likely because of the trailing commas). I'm working on making a new release 3.2.0 on all platforms, which comes with the latest refmt. If you're on OSX you can try it by just changing your dep to `bsansouci/bsb-native#3.2.0`, nuking `node_modules` and reinstalling.
Sorry for the inconvenience. I'm planning on making my release cycle tighly coupled with bsb's release cycle.